# tabulator dynamic columns from return ajax json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabulator

I'm unable to fill the tabulator with a json from ajax response. The json key is every day of a given month, ex.:

```
{data: [{"MON1": '7,56'}, {"TUE2": '4,33'}, {"WED3": '0,33'}, etc..]}
```

the tests i've done with the tabulator:

```
//first attempt, classic ajax way
$.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {year: year, month: month},
   success: tableCB
});

//table callback
function tableCB(data){
   var table = new Tabulator('#tbl', {
      data: data,
      autoColumns: true
   });
}
```

and this is what i get:
[image: attempt 1]

another test:

```
//second attempt with tabulator ajax :
var table = new Tabulator('#tbl', {
    ajaxURL: 'test.php',
    ajaxParams: {year: year, month: month},
    ajaxConfig: 'post',
    ajaxResponse: function(url, params, response){
         return response.data;
    },
    autoColumns: true
});
```

and this is the result:
[image: attempt 2]

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Hi your json array has different keys `MON1,Tue1`..etc that's why its showing only first key . You need make your json array like `{"key" : "Mon1" ," val" :"somevalue"}` where key & value will be same only `mon1` and `somevalue` will change.

Comment: Hi. key, value is not the json format expected by the tabulator component. Accordingly with their documentation, json format is an array of object like: [{colName: val1, colName2, val2, colNameX, valX}].

Comment: yes `key` is just a name you can change that

Answer (score 0):

implement a forEach

```
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {year: year, month: month},
        success: function (data) {
           $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            console.log(value);
           });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not sure about your suggestion. An 'each' inside the tabulator constructor?